# How to remove subview from Superview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have taken one subView of type UIView on the top of UIViewController. I want to remove it and again load it after clicking on button. But I am unable to remove it.
I have used [subView removeFromSuperview] method. But it is not working.

Comment: are you sure that this line is reached.  use single stepping to find out what is the problem.

Comment: It is not working cause it does not have any superview.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the method inside the AppDelegate. If you have loaded the rootViewController.view as a subview to your window, try to unload it again, you should see a white screen.

```
[self.window addSubview:rootViewController.view];
[rootViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Also, insert this line before you removeFromSuperview in your code:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[rootViewController.view superview]);
```

Replace rootViewController.view with your view. If the log reads (null), it means you have incorrectly assigned your view as a subview.